# Excel IF Else Skip Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

currently I am working at a Golfclub where I need to sort out an Excel list with hunderets of names and T-Shirt sizes. I need to sort those out between men and women.
I was wondering if it is possible to write a formula for each cell to get the needed Data?

This would be the Table where I would get all the Data from:
[image: Excel Table 1]

And in this table in a differenet sheet I need to fill out the following Data somehow (this is the table for men, but it is the same for women):

[image: Excel Table 2]

Note: The tables are in German. In the first table the m=men and w=women.

Comment: So you need help on two steps, right? One is filtering by men or women. Two, is matching the size of the t-shirt with the appropriate column on the second table.

Comment: Exactly. I don't know if it is possible to get it in the right column for the size, but that would just be a bonus.

Comment: Sorry, but what columns are you trying to fill? Vorname or NAchname? One of them must need a manual input but the rest can be filled with VLOOKUP for sure (if there are no duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I suppose you are using Excel 365. If you are using any older Excel version, please let me know so I'll update the answer.*

The easiest and clearest way is using the function "**FILTER**". It allows you to filter a range of data based on the criteria you define.

My formula for the Vorname is: `=FILTER($B$2:$B$6,$J$2:$J$6="m")`

- Column B is where the original Vorname stands, the range to filter.
- Column J contains the m or w, the condition.

After that, you just need to replicate the formula for the Nachname and for "w".

Just to give the formula for Nachname as well: `=FILTER($A$2:$A$6,$J$2:$J$6="m")`

---

Now that we have the filters explained, let's combine it with "if" to select the size of the T-Shirt.

When I replicated your table, the size name "S" filled cell D8. Consequentially, M is E8, L is F8 and so on.
Then on D9, add: `=IF(FILTER($G$2:$G$6,$J$2:$J$6="m")=D$8,D$8,"")`

- The sizes are located in column G. Therefore, the filter select the size of the correspondent person. Again, this is the table for men.
- The if clause only shows the size if it matches the name of the column (in the example, if size is "S")

The final result for men is the following.
[image: Result table for men]

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works perfectly with the Names, but when I get to the size it gives me the error code #NAME?

As I had to get it from a different sheet, I had to adjust it, but it worked with the names.
This is the formula:
=IF(FILTER(' Startliste Samstag'!H6:H48;' Startliste Samstag'!K6:K48="m")=D$3;D$3;"")

Comment: Hello there, I figured it out. Thank you very much my friend. I forgot that the work PC was set on German, so I had to change "IF" to "WENN". The german IF Formula. You are very skilled my friend! :D